# How does a registrar update the gtld name servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, whois, domain-registrar

Is there a standardized protocol how a registrar updates the NS information for a domain? For example, if, through my registrar's interface, I set the name servers for "example.com" to "ns1.example.com" and "ns2.example.com" how are [a-m].gtld-servers.net updated with this information? Does this protocol use the whois information or is that merely informational for the end user?

Edit: I see rfc3375 "Generic Registry-Registrar Protocol Requirements" but that is informational.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this matter?

Comment: @FalconMomot Because occasionally the registrar fucks this part up, and when they do, it's damn near impossible to figure out what's going on. I for one would like to hear the answer to this.

Comment: Agreed, great question.

Comment: Aah, yes, in that case it would be interesting to know.  I have yet to experience anything but excessive propagation delays with doing this.

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this. It's never been clearly explained to me how the gTLD servers get updated NS information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact details or implementations, but my understanding is that it revolves around EPP - Extensible Provisioning Protocol

> The motivation for the creation of EPP was to create a robust and
>   flexible protocol that could provide communication between domain name
>   registries and domain name registrars. These transactions are required
>   whenever a domain name is registered or renewed, thereby also
>   preventing domain hijacking. Prior to its introduction, registries had
>   no uniform approach, and many different proprietary interfaces
>   existed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Provisioning_Protocol